# centos 6.8 remote install

Tags: centos, installation, remote

I want to re-install centos 6.8 with custom partation layout on my dedicated server that comes with cent os 6.7.

I tried following settings on a vps first and i am able to connect via vnc for remote installation.

I tried same settings on the dedicated server but i am unable to connect via vnc.

downloaded following files on /

```
wget ht*tp://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/isolinux/vmlinuz -O vmlinuz-7     
wget ht*tp://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/isolinux/initrd.img -O initrd-7.img
```

edited the grub , added following lines nano /boot/grub/grub.conf

```
  title CentOS 6 VNC Installation
    root (hd0,0)
    kernel /vmlinuz-7 vnc vncpassword=12345678 headless ip=******.130 gateway=*****.129 netmask=255.255.255.248 dns=8.8.8.8 ksdevice=eth1 repo=ht*tp://mirror.centos.org/centos/6.8/os/x86_64 lang=en_US keymap=us
    initrd /initrd-7.img
```

verified that eth1 is the working network.
then

```
echo 'savedefault --default=1 --once' | grub --batch
```

and rebooted the system but never able to connect back.

How can check if there is some error ? Can I log it? , on VPS it was easy as I had vnc access. but with a dedicated server in a datacenter there must be some option to log the errors.

Answer (score 1):

The way to check is to use the remote console (IPMI, iDRAC, iLO etc). Everything right up to the point where it transfers to VNC is output to that device.

You should ask your hosting provider about this, sometimes they don't have this kind of access and have to attach a hardware KVM for you.